# decomposition of so(6) to so(4)

Tags: lie-algebras

In paper https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/jpa-00210472/document, it is said so(6) can be decomposed into $so(4) \times u(1)$. But the u(1) is from an so(2) diagonal block. i.e. say $J_{12},J_{34},J_{56}$ are Cartan elements of so(6), then pick $J_{56}$ to be the $u(1)$

I am wondering is that possible to do the decomposition by picking $u(1)$ to be $J_{12} + J_{34} +J_{56}$? Any reference has ever done that?

I prefer this may be not possible. But I cannot find any reason. Alternatively, can we choose $u(1)$ to be $J_{12} + J_{34}$

What I mean is to embed $SO(4) \times U(1)$ to $SO(6)$ by picking  $U(1)$ either $J_{12}+J_{34} +J_{56}$ or $J_{12}+J_{34} $ instead of $J_{56}$. So in short the question is if we pick $U(1)$ generator of Lie algebra to be $J_{12}+J_{34} +J_{56}$ or $J_{12}+J_{34} $, do the rest generators form $so(4)$ subalgebra? Note they all should commute with $u(1)$ generators you pick.

Comment: I don't know if you're talking of the Lie algebra or the Lie group (in both cases you're using nonstandard notation: standard notation is $\mathfrak{so}_4$ resp $\mathrm{SO}_4$). What kind of product/decomposition do you mean? $\mathrm{SO}_6$ has dimension 15 while $\mathrm{SO}_4\times\mathrm{U}(1)$ has dimension 11. I can't make much sense of what you say then.

Comment: What I mean is to embed $SO(4) \times U(1)$ to $SO(6)$ by picking  $U(1)$ either $J_{12}+J_{34} +J_{56}$ or $J_{12}+J_{34} $ instead of $J_{56}$

Comment: The second line of your post is still absurd, and you still don't clarify what you mean (homotopy equivalences? homeomorphisms? group isomorphisms? etc). Your question will probably be closed as unclear if you don't clarify this.

Answer (score 4):

So you're picking a certain element from $so(6)$ and you want to find an $so(4)$ subalgebra that commutes with it. You should be able to do this; just calculate the centralizer of that element in $so(6)$; that should come out to be the $so(4)\oplus u(1)$ you're looking for. There are 8 more generators of $so(6)$ to account for; these can be chosen to be the +1 and -1 eigenspaces of the element you picked. (PS. $so(4) \oplus u(1)$ has dimension 7 not 11)